# Adjusting in-line xy-pic diagrams to the baseline

Tags: xy-pic

I want to put a triangular-shaped diagram in a line between the text, like:

```
Consider the diagram $\xymatrix{ & \bullet \ar[dr] & \\ \bullet \ar[rr] \ar[ur] & & \bullet }$ blah blah blah
```

The problem is that the base of the triangle is placed below the baseline. Is there a way to adjust it to the base line?

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  Please code that compiles, preferably in the form of a complete small document.  Your `\xymatrix` gives many errors because of non-existent targets in rows above and below, e.g. `\ar[dr]` points down to the right, but there is no next row.  Please replace with a use-case example.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Sorry for the errors. I think it should be fine now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one possible way

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}

Consider the diagram $\xy (0,12)+{\xymatrix { & \bullet \ar[dr] & \\ \bullet
\ar[rr] \ar[ur] & & \bullet }} \endxy$ with appropriate baseline.

\end{document}
```

The `\xymatrix` produces an object that can be shifted in standard `xy` style , here by `(0,12)` in the natural coordinate system, meaning `0` to the right and `12` up.

Comment: My sincere congratulation. I want used minipage or float but I still hadn't been able to position the text well with the graph.

Answer (score 2):

You can raise the diagram by its depth (the vertical extent below the baseline), but also taking into account that the `\xymatrix` is surrounded by `\fboxsep` space around all sides.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\begin{document}

Consider the diagram
\raisebox{\dimexpr\depth-\fboxsep}{%
  $\xymatrix{ & \bullet \ar[dr] & \\ \bullet \ar[rr] \ar[ur] & & \bullet }$%
}
blah blah blah

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd also make it smaller, if you really want it to be inline.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\begin{document}

Consider the diagram
\raisebox{\dimexpr\depth-\fboxsep}{%
  $\xymatrix@R-1pc@C-1pc{ & \bullet \ar[dr] & \\ \bullet \ar[rr] \ar[ur] & & \bullet }$%
} 
blah blah blah

\end{document}
```

[image]